# Extracting content from the Hadoop Text object

Tags: hadoop

I am working with a large text inside a Text object from the Hadoop ( 0.20.203.0 ) Java library. I need to extract XML content from it without converting the whole object to a Java String ( by using .toString() ).

Could someone please give an example on how to do this?

Reading the documentation ( http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.html ), I assume that I will need to use the .decode() functions.

```
Text t = "....<content>secret</content>...."
int start = t.find("<content>");
int end = t.find("</content>", start);
t.decode(String.getBytes(), start+7, end);
```

I don't understand how to use the first parameter of the function, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks mostly correct.  The first parameter of `decode` is the byte array you want to create a String from.

From the docs:

```
public static String decode(byte[] utf8, int start, int length)
```

It says `utf8` only to say that it expects your byte buffer to be in UTF-8 format (which `Text` uses by default).  So your code would be:

```
Text.decode(t.getBytes(), start+7, end);
```

since `decode` is a static function.  Also, looking at the source for `Text`, this should not increase your memory footprint because `getBytes()` returns the reference to the underlying byte array that a `Text` object holds.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I could find the solution to the specific problem of **parsing the content between two XML tags**:

```
int start = t.find("<content>", 0);
int end = t.find("</content>", start);
int advance = "<content>".length();

try {
  content = Text.decode(t.getBytes(), start+advance, end-start-advance);
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("IOException was " + e.getMessage());
}
```

The last parameter is the length of the content to extract, not its final position (which was the mistake in the initial post).